# How to create a shortcut to toggle Chrome Settings on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, automator

In Mac Chrome, I like to switch the default, global Page Zoom settings from 100% to 125%. I'd like a shortcut to do it quickly instead of needing to go to Settings, click Show Advanced Settings, and finally changing the Web Content Page Zoom.

I wonder if there's a way to create an Automator shortcut / hot key? I'm new to Mac so unsure of these tricks.

To be clear, I already know about changing zoom settings Per Website by clicking Command +/-

Comment: In OS X, this setting is saved in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Preferences`, a JSON file that you can edit directly. It's the `default_zoom_level` key. Just need to find a proper way to toggle this externally.

Comment: I have no idea how to "toggle this externally". Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You could write a shell script to toggle the value of that key in the JSON file, wrap it in an Automator action, and assign a shortcut to that.

Comment: How would I do that in a shell script? Do you have a search and replace method that would find that particular value and change it?

Answer (score 1):

I have to post this as an answer rather than a comment (as I don't have enough rep), but you can use `sed` and/or `awk` to find the particular line of text you're looking for and replace the default value with whatever value is needed to zoom to your liking. I looked at my `Preferences` JSON file, but I didn't seem to have the `default_zoom_level` key, so I can't tell you exactly how to do it, but I did some tests on a sample file using a variation of this script:

`cat PATHTOCHROMEPREFERENCES | sed s/ORIGINALVALUE/NEWVALUE/ | pbcopy | pbpaste > PATHTOCHROMEPREFERENCES`

where `ORIGINALVALUE` is the value is the default 100% zoom and `NEWVALUE` is whatever you need to enter to zoom to 125%. As I mentioned above, I didn't see the `default_zoom_level` key in the file I have, so I cannot verify that this will work in this specific file.

The `sed` command used here should be able to and replace whatever text you want, but I suspect you will need to use `awk` as well to find the specific line you're looking for, since there seems to be a lot of lines containing `default_` in the file.

There is probably a much more elegant way to do this, but I hope my answer helps!